# Flutter video player init() has not been implemented error

Tags: android, ios, iphone, flutter, dart

I got an error that says

> [UnimplementedError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2leQ.png)(UnimplementedError: init() has not been
> implemented.)

I tried this code and expected to work fine but I got an error like in this image.

Comment: can you include code-snippet

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the video player in this way:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initVideoPlayer();
  }
```

By creating an **asynchronization** method

```
  void _initVideoPlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');

    /// Initialize the video player
    await videoPlayerController.initialize();

    /// The rest of your code
    final chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
    );

    final playerWidget = Chewie(
      controller: chewieController,
    );
  }
```